# How to navigate through jsp pages in drop down menu?

Tags: jsp, button, href

I have two king of registration form.First page provide a button name Registration.By moving cursor over it, it will display dropdown menu.If I select option 1 Registration, I want to navigate to jsp page 1 ans If I select option 2 registration , I want to get jsp page 2.How can I do that?

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button> REGISTRATION </button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#register_user"onclick="document.location.href('C_registration.jsp')">as user</a>
<a href="#register_photostudio_owner"onclick="document.location.href('PSO_registration')">as photostudio owner</a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add in your struts config file as well as controller class!

Comment: Could you post,as to what went wrong and how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Map 2 Jsp's in web.xml as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index1.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<!--mapping-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test1/*</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index2.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<!--mapping-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test2/*</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your links should be
[Test1](/test1)
[Test2](/test2)

Comment: I am using struts

Comment: You can refer to the below link.

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-dispatch-action-example-1.html